# Alternative method for function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know is there any alternative method for a function in my scenario in javascript

Below function works fine, but is there any alternative method to do, since there are more `obj`

```
//will get single object as response as anyof these 
obj ={"id":"trans", "cn": "SG", "ccy": "SGD"};
obj ={"id": "remit", "cn": "TH", "ccy": "THB"};
obj ={"id": "fund", "cn": "IN", "ccy": "INR"};

function getTrans(){
  var value = 1000;
  var rate = 0.5;
  return value * rate;
}

function getFund(){
  var value = 2000;
  var rate = 0.2;
  return value * rate;
}

var result = getData(obj);

function getData(obj){
 if(obj.id==="trans"){
  return  getTrans(obj);
  }
 else if(obj.id==="fund"){
  return   getFund(obj);
 }
else{
  return obj;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why there are multiple `var obj`  in the code?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt thanks for reply , will get response each time in above format `obj` there will be single obj only, will get trans or fund or insta

Comment: Looks fine, i wouldn't change anything because this code is pretty readable and not overbloaten.

Comment: If you are sure that the value and rate are going to remain constant, then I would not bother writing separate functions but directly return the multiplied value.

Answer (score 1):

You would usually write a map letting you access your function, for example

```
//will get object as response 
var obj ={"id":"trans", "cn": "SG", "ccy": "SGD"};
var obj ={"id": "remit", "cn": "TH", "ccy": "THB"};
var obj ={"id": "fund", "cn": "IN", "ccy": "INR"};

const extractors = {
    trans(obj) { 
        var value = 1000;
        var rate = 0.5;
        return value * rate;// this should probably use obj
    },
    fund(obj) {
        var value = 2000;
        var rate = 0.2;
        return value * rate;
    }
}

function getData(obj){
    let extractor = extractors[obj.id];
    return extractor ? extractor(obj) : obj;
}

var result = getData(obj);
```

If you have other similar functions to associate to your ids, you could use objects instead of functions:

```
const handlers = {
     trans: {
           getData: obj => ...,
           foo: obj => ...
     },
     ...
```

and then access the functions with

```
 function getData(obj){
     let handler = handlers[obj.id];
     return handler ? handler.getData(obj) : obj;
 }
```

This kind of pattern is very extensible and is suited to injections, meaning you can have a global getData code not aware of the various types, but other parts of your applications registering new handlers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class ObjX{
  constructor(id,cn,ccy){
   this.id=id;
   this.cn=cn;
   this.ccy=ccy;
  }
  trans=function(){
    var value = 1000;
    var rate = 0.5;
    return value * rate;
  }
  fund=function(){
    var value = 2000;
    var rate = 0.2;
    return value * rate;
  }
  getData(){
   if(this[this.id]){
    return  this[this.id]();
   }else{
    return this;
   }
  }
 }
 obj =new ObjX("trans","SG","SGD");
 obj2 =new ObjX("remit","TH","THB");
 obj3 =new ObjX("fund","SG","INR");
 
  
 
 console.log(obj.trans());
 
 
 
 console.log(obj.getData());
 console.log(obj2.getData());
 console.log(obj3.getData());
```

Try this magic!